# AJAX form submission to Django Class View

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I'm trying to submit data to model using Ajax, its gives a 403 (Forbidden), view I'm using is a Class View. Things works fine without Ajax. How to do the same with ajax ?

My Url :

```
 path('add_to_cart/<slug>', views.AddToCartView.as_view(), name='add_to_cart'),
```

My View :

```
class AddToCartView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

     model = Wishlist

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.request.user)
        print(self.kwargs['slug'])
        wished_product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        product,created  = self.model.objects.get_or_create(product=wished_product,
                       customer = self.request.user)
    return HttpResponse(status=201)
```

and ajax call

```
  $('.buy').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let _this = $(this);
        var slug = _this.data('id');

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'add_to_cart/'+ slug +'/',
            success: function(data){
                if(data.success = true){
                    _this.addClass('clicked');
                }
            },
            async : false,
            error : function(data){
                alert(data);
            }

        })

    });
```

When i use 'POST' instead of 'GET' in Ajax type it gives 404 (Not Found)

Comment: you have not created any `post` method in your `AddToCartView` class. And for the `get` method, you are using the `LoginRequiredMixin` but how are you sending any login info through `ajax`. Are you using tokens?

Comment: POST method gives 404